# I have 10 points inn x-axis, ranging [-25,-20,,-15,-10,0,10,20,30,40,50]. But I want my line chart to start from -15 of x-axis. How we can achieve?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have 10 points  inn x-axis, ranging [-25,-20,-10,0,10,20,30,40,50]. But I want my line chart to start from -15 of x-axis. How we can achieve?
Below is the code i tried with suggestedmin and suggestedmax but it didnt worked.
Please suggest some way to achieve this

```js
export class CgChartComponent {
  lineChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
    { data: [3145000, 3430001, 1499998, 1700000, 3515340, 2480011], label: 'ABC', lineTension: 0, },
  ];
 
  lineChartLabels: Label[] = ['-25','-20','-15', '-10', '0', '10', '20', '30','40','50' ];
  lineChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    responsiveAnimationDuration: 30,
    legend: {
      position: 'bottom'
  },
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          suggestedMin:  -15,
          suggestedMax:  40
        }
    }]
}
  };

  lineChartColors: Color[] = [
    {
      borderColor: 'black',
     
    },
  ];

  lineChartLegend = true;
  lineChartPlugins = [];
  lineChartType = 'line';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `min` and `max` instead of `suggestedMin` and `suggestedMax` as follows:

```
xAxes: [{
  ticks: {
    min:  -15,
    max:  40
  }
}]
```

> From Chart.js documentation
>
> [Axis Range Settings](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html#axis-range-settings)
>
> The `suggestedMax` and `suggestedMin` settings only change the data values that are used to scale the axis. These are useful for extending the range of the axis while maintaining the auto fit behaviour.
>
> [Tick Configuration](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/#tick-configuration)
>
> `min`: User defined minimum value for the scale, overrides minimum value from data.
>
> `max`: User defined maximum value for the scale, overrides maximum value from data.

**UPDATE**

The problem is probably that the labels are strings but `min` and `max` are defined as numbers. This can be solved in two different ways.

Either you transform the labels into numbers or you define `min` and `max` as follows:

```
xAxes: [{
  ticks: {
    min: '-15',
    max: '40'
  }
}]
```

Comment: Tried that also but it didnt work out
scales: {
      xAxes: [
        {
          scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
            labelString: 'MAC',
          },
          ticks: {
            min:  -15,
            max:  40
          },
        },
      ],
    },